# Grunt - pass target to a task

Tags: gruntjs

I'm registering a task to perform other tasks:

```
grunt.registerTask('foo', function (target) {
    grunt.task.run(['bar',..]);

})
grunt.registerTask('bar', [
    'baz:<target>',
    ...
]);
```

I want the target of baz to be the target argument specified to a foo function. Can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to register **bar** task in the same way as **foo** task?

```
grunt.registerTask('foo', function (target) {
  grunt.task.run(['bar' + (target ? ':' + target : '')]);
});

grunt.registerTask('bar', function (target) {
  grunt.task.run(['baz' + (target ? ':' + target : '')]);
});
```